# How to trigger button with keyboard and active

Tags: javascript, button, events, triggers

I want to trigger a button with keyboard and with mouse.
It works, but the :active does not show if I trigger it with keyboard.

HTML

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="btn1()"> click </button>
```

CSS

```
#btn1:active{
transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === '1') {
      document.getElementById("btn1").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use Javascript add/remove class for this use case.

In the `keydown` eventListner add the active class. Add another eventListner for `keyup` and then remove that active class.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
      btn.click();
      btn.classList.add('active');
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
      btn.classList.remove('active');
});

function btn1(){
  
}
```

```css
#btn1:active{
transform:scale(1.1);
}
.active{
transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="btn1()"> click </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **selector.style**

and use **setTimeout()** to transfrom to default scale

**Example :**

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.key == "1"){
        clicked(document.getElementById("btn1"));
        document.getElementById("btn1").click();
    }
});

function clicked(el){
    el.style.transform = "scale(1.1)";
    setTimeout(()=>{ el.removeAttribute('style'); }, 100);
}
```

```css
#btn1:active{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="//btn1()"> click </button>
```